# Pandas update values in a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

How can I edit a values of a multi-index dataframe? If it was a non-multi-index dataframe, I know I could do this: `df.at[0,'foo'] = 12.3`.
Also, this does not work: `df.loc[0]['foo']['a'] = 12.3`.

Consider a multi-index column dataframe.

```
colnames = [
    ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'po', 'po', 'po', 'di', 'di', 'di'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=colnames, index=arange(5))

display(df)
   foo             po             di          
     a    b    c    a    b    c    a    b    c
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 17):

Use `tuple`s for select `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df.loc[0, ('foo','a')] = 12.3
print (df)
    foo             po             di          
      a    b    c    a    b    c    a    b    c
0  12.3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

If need more complicated updating use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[0, idx['foo', ['b','c']]] = 12.3
print (df)
   foo               po             di          
     a     b     c    a    b    c    a    b    c
0  NaN  12.3  12.3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

```
df.loc[0, idx[:, ['b','c']]] = 12.3
print (df)
   foo               po               di            
     a     b     c    a     b     c    a     b     c
0  NaN  12.3  12.3  NaN  12.3  12.3  NaN  12.3  12.3
1  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
2  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
3  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
4  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

---

```
df.loc[:, idx[['po','di'], 'a']] = 12.3
print (df)
   foo              po              di          
     a    b    c     a    b    c     a    b    c
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  12.3  NaN  NaN  12.3  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  12.3  NaN  NaN  12.3  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  12.3  NaN  NaN  12.3  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  12.3  NaN  NaN  12.3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  12.3  NaN  NaN  12.3  NaN  NaN
```